# code-line 26:43 giving no-shadow:no-shadow

Tags: javascript

so i wrote this piece of code for a project but now my ESLinter keeps giving me a no-shadow:no-shadow error on line 26:43 any ideas on how to fix this?

```
const selectionButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-selection]');
const finalColumn = document.querySelector('[data-final-column]');
const computerScoreSpan = document.querySelector('[data-computer-score]');
const yourScoreSpan = document.querySelector('[data-your-score]');
const SELECTIONS = [
    {
        name: 'rock',
        emoji: '✊',
        beats: 'scissors',
    },
    {
        name: 'paper',
        emoji: '✋',
        beats: 'rock',
    },
    {
        name: 'scissors',
        emoji: '✌',
        beats: 'paper',
    },
];

selectionButtons.forEach(selectionButton => {
    selectionButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const selectionNames = selectionButton.dataset.selection;
        const selectionchoice = SELECTIONS.find(selection => selection.name === selectionNames);
        makeSelection(selectionchoice);
    });
});
```

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow
I don't see any line numbers, but I would assume it's either the `selection` parameter in the lambda, or you are redefining something that has not been included in the code fragment above.

Comment: well i tried to rename one of the variables on line 26:43 being :

const selection = SELECTIONS.find(selection => selection.name === selectionNames);

but in doing so the name turns grey and stops working the code all together

Answer (score 1):

You define a variable named `selection` here:

> ```
> const selection = SELECTIONS
> ```

And you define another variable named `selection` here:

> ```
> selection => selection....
> ```

And the latter [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the former.

---

Rename one of the variables.

Comment: tried that already but then my whole code stops working

Comment: Presumably you didn't change all references to the renamed variable to match the new name, so you had some code referring to the other variable which used to have the same name … but when you provide a description of what you did instead of a [mcve] and tell us nothing more than it [doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) we don't have a lot to go on.

Comment: can you update the code where you've changed the variable name? @Brave-N8tionOfficial

Comment: after reading the comments i changed line 26 to this :
 const selectionchoice = SELECTIONS.find(selection => selection.name === selectionNames);
and it works now